# Upload image and video on background without using asynch task in Android

Tags: android

I need to upload some data like Image and Video to server using Xml web service. I am able to upload using asynch task in Android but I need to upload all data to server in background means there should not be display any progress bar.

So I think to use service for achieving the same, is using a service the right approach? How could I convert activity to service. Are there any other ways to achieve this?

I am writing below my code on button click event for asynch task:

```
  UploadDataInBackground uploader = new UploadDataInBackground();
  uploader.execute(ReplyForm.this, true, replyform);    // it is asynch class
```

Comment: Please do not roll back good edits to your posts. I have downvoted as a helpful reminder.

Answer (score 1):

You should continue doing this in an AsyncTask. If you do not want a progress dialog to be shown, simpl, remove or comment that part of the the code out. It should be in you onPreExecute (), and onPostExecute ().

Comment: yeah thats exactly i have done , but i need to refresh the activity list when data uploaded succesfull , and if we leave that activity while executing DoinBackGround() and when it try to refresh list , then force close occurs..

Comment: how to schedule the process of uploading in queue?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using ResultReceiver. I have made an application where I upload large video to a  server and used something like this:

```
public class MyResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

    public final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private Receiver mReceiver;

    public TmResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("MyResultReceiver", "onReceiveResult");
        if( mReceiver != null ){
            mReceiver.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        }
    }

    public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
        //Log.d("MyResultReceiver", "setReceiver");
        mReceiver = receiver;
    }

    public interface Receiver {
        public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData);
    }   

}
```

Comment: Hi LAzy Ninza ... have you used service for uploading in back ground?

Answer (score 0):

just implement your own `Service`, see this post for downloading file using `Services, but you must implement your own upload`Service` ,, [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)